# Can't add custom fields to Calendar

Tags: views, datetime

I've created a new content type event (With title, body and date), but I can't select the type when editing my calendar view (screenshot included).

How come I can only select comments and dates, ..?

[image: view filter]

edit: it's because I added a view from template (Comments). How do you change the type of this view from comments to content? Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot change View types (i.e. Users to Content or Content to Comments etc.).
You will have to start the view from scratch.

Comment: Why aren't there any calendar view templates using content instead of comment? It would make a lot more sense to me to use them over comments. Or am I not seeing this right?

Comment: I updated my answer with a feature I made that should help you figure out the correct configuration for your view.

Comment: Link is now 404.